# Xscreensaver doesn't start on login

Tags: arch-linux, xscreensaver

OS: Arch Linux (systemd)
UI: LXDM logging in to Openbox.

I have the following in my /etc/lxdm/PostLogin:

```
/usr/bin/xscreensaver -no-splash -verbose -log /var/log/xscreensaver.log -display :0.0 &
```

It doesn't start xscreensaver. I've tried variations on the command, with /usr/bin, without, with -display, without, without -verbose... Nothing. No log messages, nothing on dmesg, nothing.

If I run xscreensaver daemon after login, it works, but that's a hassle for something that should work just fine. Yes, the same autostarting file does get my batti and nm-applet working fine, so it's not the file, it's the program, crashing. How do I stop it from crashing?

Any advice?

Edit:

```
$ which xscreensaver
/usr/bin/xscreensaver
```

Comment: whats the output of `which xscreensaver`?

Comment: /usr/bin/xscreensaver

Comment: what happens if you type /usr/bin/xscreensaver in a terminal?  It should tell you xscreensaver is already running on display XX because xscreensaver is forked after X starts automatically IIRC

Comment: It works. If I start the daemon after login, it works just fine, I just have to do it manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do it manually.  This is one reason xscreensaver is a dependency of X, the screensaver runs automatically while X is running, even when its not in use... it counts the time you do nothing.  If the time you do nothing = your set time the screensaver starts

Comment: I start the daemon. That means it runs in the background, it does start automatically, but I have to type in the command to start the daemon so it runs in the background.

Comment: Restart, then startx, then go to your screensaver settings, make sure the screensaver option exists,  on my laptop(xubuntu) and my desktop(gentoo) they each run w/o intervention.

Comment: Mr. @Young, you seem to forget that I'm using Openbox with a display manager. A) No startx. B) No screensaver settings.

Comment: This was the only option on the [Ubuntu Wiki for Openbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox#Screensaver).  
`xscreensaver -no-splash`, so let's try removing the extra options

Comment: No effect. You do realize that Ubuntu uses Gnome or Unity around Openbox? Openbox is a window manager: It shows windows. Gnome and Unity, which are what Ubuntu use to do stuff like search bars and dragging icons to do things, and so on and so forth (the whole "unified" thing) are a Desktop Environment, which can include a Window Manager.

Comment: Does [this base copy of xinit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xinitrc#Configuration) from Arch help?

Comment: It helped me debug a problem... now see my edits to the question based on that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out /var/log/xscreensaver.log was the problem: it could not be written to for ownership conflicts. I had set it as a log in .Xresources, so the problem was not obvious.